# Currying out of order in Haskell

Tags: haskell, currying

Is there an elegant notation for Currying the arguments of a function out of order in Haskell?

For example, if you wish to divide 2 by all elements of a list, you can write

```
map ((/) 2) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

However to divide all elements of a list it seems you need to define an anonymous function

```
map (\x -> x/2) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Anonymous functions quickly become unwieldy in more complex cases.  I'm aware that in this case map ((*) 0.5) [1,2,3,4,5] would work fine, but I'm interested to know if Haskell has a more elegant way of currying arguments of a function out of order?

Comment: `flip` and backticks are good along with simply using the infix function (as delnan points out).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In this particular case:

```
Prelude> map (/2) [1..5]
[0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5]
```

Not only you can use an infix operator as ordinary prefix function, you can also partially apply it in infix form. Likewise, the first example would better be written as `map (2/) [1..5]`

Also, there's `flip` which is not quite as elegant, but still the best option available for ordinary functions (when you don't want to turn them into infix via backticks):

```
Prelude> let div' = (/)
Prelude> div' 2 1
2.0
Prelude> flip div' 2 1
0.5
```

Comment: Does this only work with operators? What about arbitrary functions?

Comment: @Gabe: As FUZxxl wrote, it also works with  functions that are used infix (by surrounding them with backticks). I'd provide an example, but he already provided one.

Comment: Thank you.  It is a shame there is no syntax such as f 1 2 # 4 #, that has the same effect as \x y -> f 1 2 x 4 y.

Comment: @hosiers: Actually, for tuples there is an extension for this: Stick `{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}` on top and you can do `('a',,1,,)` instead of `\x y z -> ('a',x,1,y,z)`, but for functions - I've yet to see this.

Answer (score 2):

For your second one, the lambda is unnecessary, just use like:

```
map (/2) [1..5]
```

The form (/2) simply means, that you want to access the second param of an operator. It is also possible with the first argument `(2/)`. This is called a **section**, and is a really useful hack, not only in code golf. You can also use it in prefix functions, if you use them infix:

```
map (`div` 2) [1..5]
```

In more difficult cases, like 3 or more arguments, you're supposed to use lambdas, as it becomes more readable most times.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a generalized solution, like the `cut` in scheme. Right?

There is the `flip` function that *reverse the first 2 arguments* of a function.  There may be other functions doing a similar task (I'm not too good at Haskell... yet).

Comment: `flip` doesn't reverses the argument list. It Just flips the first two, consider this: `flip (.) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c`. -1

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a [very similar issue](http://gaiustech.wordpress.com/2010/09/19/scope-in-database-code-2/) myself recently, and I wasn't able to find an elegant solution other than using a helper function to do it:

```
dbfunc f b c = (\a -> liftIO $ f a b c)
deleteAllRows = do
  ask >>= dbfunc run "delete from t1" []
```

At least this pattern is common enough in HDBC that dbfunc is reusable.

Comment: `ask >>= liftIO . (flip . (flip run) "delete from t1" [])`

Comment: For certain values of elegant ;-)