# Haskell MonadWriter type signature

Tags: haskell, monads, writer, type-signature

Noob question on MonadWriter:

```
monadWrite :: Writer String Int
monadWrite = writer (3003, "log 1\n")
```

Why is it that `String` comes first in the typesig and `Int` second, while `3003` is clearly an `Int` while `"log 1\n"` is a `String`. 
Trivial I know, but I would like to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no particular reason to put the result (`3003`) first and the output (`"log 1\n"`) second in the argument to `writer`. The order was, I suppose, chosen to correspond to the [internal representation of `WriterT`](https://stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.14/transformers-0.5.5.0/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Strict.html#WriterT):

```
newtype WriterT w m a = WriterT { runWriterT :: m (a, w) }
```

(for `Writer`, `m` is identity).

However, in the type signature for `Writer`, the order of arguments matters. If we look at, for example, the `Functor` typeclass with a member

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

it makes it possible to substitute `Writer String` (or generally, `Writer result`) for `f` and obtain

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Writer result a -> Writer result b
```

which is exactly the correct order of arguments. Swapping them would make implementing `Functor` impossible (without some trickery).

This is true for all types/functions which take more than one parameter: the only way they can be used as one-argument types/functions is by varying the last argument, not the other ones.

See related questions discussing similar issues:

[Switch order of arguments for instance declaration in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927048/switch-order-of-arguments-for-instance-declaration-in-haskell)

[Currying out of order in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789190/currying-out-of-order-in-haskell)